# Remove gutter gap from div in Bootstrap 2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

Please note I have inherited an project and **MUST** use Bootstrap 2.

I have the following code that displays the site logo in the top-left of the page, for some reason this image is being "pushed" to the right due to the gutter when using the grid system - how do I remove this gap for this single row?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span12">
     <img src="/img/logo.png">
  </div>
</div><!-- end row -->
```

Any advice would be appreciated and please note this is using Bootstrap 2 rather than the newer improved Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class, and set to margin 0

```css
.nogutter {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row nogutter">
  <div class="span12">
    <img src="/img/logo.png">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end row -->
```

Comment: weird.. this doesn't seem to work for me although your code looks spot on... i'll look through must be something else clashing

Comment: You can try put !important in the rule...i update the css code. This means that your rule is above all others.

Comment: It should by `margin: 0px !important;` fyi